# Deploy a monorepo's subdirectory on AWS CodeDeploy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I have a monorepo like so:

```
my-monorepo:
  - services/
    - appspec.yml
    - ...
  - website/
    - appspec.yml
    - ...
```

I want to deploy the `website`, but not `services`. How can I do this using AWS CodeDeploy?

It would be best to configure CodeDeploy to use `website/appspec.yml`, however I cannot see how to do this. Any help with this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A different, but related, question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/46655997/3966682